# What is the MCU-Pinmode equivalent of a button-press to ground in this scenario?

Tags: transistors, switches, input, pins

The more I think about it the more I confuse myself...  In the attached circuit if I want to simulate the effect of SW1 (or SW2) closing to ground how do I set the MCU-pin?  Connect to Terminal 2 of the SW to one MCU-pin, and via Pinmode-set to INPUT for high impedance when the SW is OPEN?  And then DigitalWrite-LOW while in INPUT (for low impedance) to CLOSE the SW?  Or I need to change Pinmode to OUTPUT and then LOW (for low impedance) to close the SW?

I think I got the NPN transistor "switch":  connect Base to a pin and set Pinmode-OUTPUT-HIGH if I want the transistor to conduct to E from C. And then set to Pinmode INPUT (no pullup) for high impedance to stop it from conducting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for simulating a button you must have a low output to ground it or high-impedance input (no pull-up or pull-down) to let the pin float.

For driving the transistor, you can just have an output that is set low or high. No need to change it to a floating input.

However the VIN must never exceed the MCU supply voltage, if SW is connected to MCU IO pin.